# Laravel route returning page not found, refusing to run attached function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form which I send to a route using POST, once it gets to this route, I instruct it to run a function within a controller, what it then does is return a 400 error. At first I thought it was due to Laravel not processing my new route in the web.php file. I went on SSH and did a  route:list and my new route was there.

I also refreshed the routes cache and emptied it, still to no avail.

The interesting however is if I put the wrong function name on the route, Laravel flags and error and declares the function doesn't exist, but when I change the function name to my actual function name, it comes up with a 400 error. I admit it could be the function itself but I expect it to throw an error n what's wrong with it rather than a 400!

```html
             <form action="{{ url('/all-events') }}" method="POST"> {{ csrf_field() }}  
                            <div class="product-showing mb-40">
                               <input  autocomplete="false" value="{{ucfirst($lowercase_city)}}" hidden name="city"> 
                               <button class="btn" type="submit">
                                        <span class="btn-text">View Events in {{ucfirst($lowercase_city)}}</span> <span class="btn-border"></span>
                               </button>

                            </div>
              </form>
```

And then my route is set up as

```
Route::post('all-events', 'FrontendController@post_all_events')->name('event.post_all_events')
```

My functions is

```
    public function post_all_events(Request $request)
    {       
        $city_name = $request->city;        

        $city = Town::findOrFail($city_name);       

        $lowercase_city = Str::lower($city->town);

        return redirect('/all-events/'.$lowercase_city);        
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the route for `parties` in your question.

Comment: You probably want to redirect to `return redirect('/all-events/'.$lowercase_city); ` rather than to `return redirect('/parties/'.$lowercase_city); `

Comment: @Nathanael My bad , yes I am redirecting to that route you stated. Editted it now.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect to a page that has a create route, ie:

```
return redirect()->route('parties', ['city' => $lowercase_city]);
```

Then create the route for it, ie:

```
Route::get('parties/{city}', 'YourController@functionName');
```

Hope this helps,